# username and password on owa exchange server 2007 invalid

Tags: exchange-2007

I installed Exchange 2007 on Windows Server 2008 R2, then I configured OWA on it. But when I try to login to my mailbox I got this message:

```
"The user name or password that you entered is not valid. Try entering it again"
```

I checked the username and password and it's true, also I trace URL and it seems to be okay.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: I work with Hossam, but he's away for a few days.

@rihatum
Yes, the other machine is still powered on, but a tracert of the owa site proves correct. And yes, navigating to the log in page is no problem, the signing in is. I have no idea why that is. This has us completely stumped.

@Jason Berg
I didn't even know you could do it from without exchange!

This server hosts only mail. So it has the default site only that contains the sites that come with an MS Exchange installation. (logs below)

I'm not seeing anything wrong with the global catalog settings.
Exporting the server config

Answer (score 1):

Are you entering the username in the correct format? Depending on how it's configured, it could be one of the following:

DOMAIN\Username    (this is the default)
Username
Username@your-dns-fqdn.com

Comment: Its configured as username only with the domain pre-configured.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring one of the mailboxes in outlook first, then login via OWA and it should work

http://exchangepedia.com/blog/2006/12/bulk-mailbox-enabling-users-exchange-shell.html

Comment: The users are configured already and all have OWA enabled.  Everything worked fine until we moved the mailboxes from the old machine (that we want to reclaim for another purpose). Everything still works with the exception of OWA.

Comment: So you have moved your Exchange to a new box ?
Is the old box still powered on ?
have you made sure that your OWA url is not pointing towards your old box ?

On your New Exchange / CAS Server can you open up a web browser and browse to https://localhost/owa  or 
https://NEWservername/owa from any lan computer

Comment: hello everyone this is hossam,

i hope that you see the log files that mustafa posted it.

many thanks for help us.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to properly configure the domain for OWA. There is a right way and a wrong way to do this. If you configured this through IIS, you did it the wrong way. Reverse whatever you did and do this:

From Exchange Management Console, open up Server Configuration -> Client Access. Under the OWA tab, right click the OWA application and go to properties. Click on the authentication tab. Use forms based authentication, user name only, and browse for the proper logon domain.

If this still doesn't work, you might have a DNS issue or are lacking the proper prereqs at the site (like the global catalog server). How many sites do you have? What does your Active Directory setup look like? Can you post IIS logs so we can see what the error is there?